# How to remove first character if it is comma in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset in Dataframe like:

```
A  B
a  ,FL,GA,KL
b  CA
c  ,KS
```

some of the values in column B start with a comma. How I can remove first comma of those cells which are started with a comma. My code is in python.

Thanks

Comment: That's a comma, not a semicolon.

Comment: `df['B'] = df['B'].str.lstrip(',')`

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Open data and put each line into data[]
with open("mydatafile.txt") as datafile:
    data = datafile.read().split("\n")

newdata = []
for line in data:
    if line[0] == ",": # Remove comma or whatever if its there
        line = line[1:]
    newdata.append(line)

# Write new data to file
with open("mynewdatafile.txt","w+") as newdatafile:
    for line in newdata:
        newdatafile.write(line+"\n")
```

That should work

Answer (score 1):

We can't really see your table, but I can see your problem.
To remove the first character of a string(for this example, it's stored in a variable called `cell`) IF it is a semicolon(or comma? It's in the var `first_letter`), use this:

```py
cell[1:] if cell[0] == first_letter else cell
```

This returns the value you want for that cell. You can loop over all your cells if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. How I can apply it in data frame?

Comment: In what form is it? A 2D matrix or something else?

Comment: Yes, I use pandas

Comment: I don't know how to use that, so this is all I can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

You can `replace` with a regex:

```
>>> df['B'].replace({'^,':''}, regex=True)
0    FL,GA,KL
1          CA
2          KS
Name: B, dtype: object
>>>
```